# Can I call a phone number from the Terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line, ios

In Yosemite, is there a way to start a phone call from the command-line aka Terminal?

Something like:

```
call +316123456789
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can with `open "tel://+316123456789"` start a phone call process - but you still need to click on the "Call" button to make the call.

[image]

To do so, you may also simply press <kbd>↩</kbd>. To automate everything via Applescript:

```
open location "tel://+351918306031"
delay 2
tell application "System Events" to key code 36
```

Comment: What app does this?

Comment: This is "Phone calls via iPhone" - also known as "Mac + iOS Continuity" (Yosemite + iOS8).

Comment: FWIW it appears that pressing the Enter/Return key will press the 'Call' button, which may make automating this a little easier.

Comment: If you don't have an iPhone, this will call using FaceTime, so the receiver will need to be an address that has that.

Comment: I tried using this method for creating a "one-click" phone number to automate testing a menu system. The number eventually got too long, and it stopped working.

Comment: What do I do if my Mac chooses to open Skype instead of FaceTime? EDIT: Ok, the flag `-a FaceTime` fixes this!

Comment: On macOS Monterey, the keycode 36 or the return key doesn't seem to work - pressing return doesn't call and the prompt is still there.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you could use [Automator](http://www.macosxautomation.com/automator/) to setup a sequence of actions to trigger making a call.  I've never actually used Automator, but my understanding of it says it'll work.

First, you could create an Automator script that perhaps triggers Rene's answer of running `open "tel://+316123456789"` *and* clicking the 'Call' button. Or, you could have it open the Google Hangouts Chrome Extension and similarly dial a number.

Second, you would call the Automator script from the command line (as described [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060805092715125)):

```
open MyAutomatorCaller.app --args '+316123456789'
```

Lastly, you could create a Bash alias for the above command (i.e. in ~/.bash_profile):

```
call() { 
    open MyAutomatorCaller.app --args $1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had added this function to my .bashrc

```
function call {
  open -a FaceTime "tel://$1"
}
```

This required FaceTime to be able to call landlines or mobile numbers (so you need an iPhone with the same AppleID as well).